# What can/should be done to improve usage of the tag [students]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This is a bag-o-worms I know. The tag [students](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/students) has been applied to nearly 500 questions, but the usage is extremely inconsistent. It doesn't seem to have any consistency at all and could be applied (as it is) to about half the questions here.

It needs a better description for a start, but is there anything else the community can do to regularize the usage? And, given the state of it, what should the description say?

Comment: Well done! That was quite the effort to get to all of them.

Comment: @BryanKrause, it took a while, but sometimes just lessened boredom when the site was slow. I've been doing a lot of other tag maintenance along the way. Now, if I could just catch a little rep...

Comment: Ah yes, always chasing the tail of the one in first place :)

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for bringing this up. I suspect a few of our tags have similar issues, including [professors](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professors). But let's start with this one for now. My two cents....

So first, we already have an [undergraduate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate) tag. This is for questions related to providing teaching, advising, or research mentorship to undergraduate students, and excludes questions that could also be relevant for post-graduate students.

We do not have a corresponding [graduate-student](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-student) tag. However, we do have a [supervision](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supervision) tag, which in practice covers most of the academic services that faculty provide to grad students.

So, I am not sure why we need a [students](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/students) tag at all. Most questions "about students" (e.g., their characteristics and preferences) should use the [undergraduate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate), [supervision](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supervision), or [teaching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tags. Questions from students should use the appropriate tag (e.g., [advisor](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advisor) or [academic-integrity](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/academic-integrity) or [grades](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grades) or whatever the issue is). If there are on-topic questions from students about issues not covered by our existing tags, we should create those tags rather than falling back to a generic "students" tag.

Sadly, the only way to implement this would be to remove the tag from all 449 questions (which will bump each of the old questions back to the front page). We could do a couple per day for the next few months, but this is a major decision; we should make sure we want to do this before we commit to it.

Comment: There are a couple of "easy" things. One is to stay vigilant about new questions and retag them as needed. The other is to retag questions that are worth bringing to the top. And improved wiki might help also. The easiest cases to judge are the closed questions, but bringing them to the top doesn't serve much purpose. FWIW, I may have just earned the tag badge for this, though the system either lost it or is slow in awarding it.

Comment: That may be a good first step -- retagging the useful questions that are worth bringing to the top. There may even be a few "useless" questions we can just delete. Then we can see where we are and decide how to proceed.

Comment: I'm currently looking at a few old (the oldest) questions, especially those that are still open, with few answers and none accepted. If they seem worthy of promotion (to me, at least), I may edit and change/remove the tag. So far just one. The numbers are daunting.

Comment: Would you think it reasonable if I flag a few questions I deem "useless"? I'd mark them for mod attention and suggest removal. Those closed as off topic and with no answers seem likely candidates. I have one in mind now. And, I notice you've retagged a few in the past few hours.

Comment: @Buffy - yupp, please do.

Comment: I've flagged all of them without answers that are closed. One, however, wasn't off topic but lacked clarity and was never edited.

Comment: I flagged one for which mine was the only answer. I'm actually trying to set some bounds here. If you reject any of these flags I'll have some guidance. But I'm getting cautious, also. Maybe we want a chat room for this "discussion".

Comment: I'd be inclined to leave [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/159176); it got some discussion, a well-received answer, and even the decision to close it is debatable. So maybe this is the lower bound on questions we want to keep.

Comment: I think both decisions are fine. Thanks.

Comment: For some of the questions I'd like to "fix" and therefore promote have user Buffy (cough) as the only current answer. Is this ok? Some guidance would be appreciated. It's not like I need the rep, of course (cough, cough).

Comment: Haha, there are very few questions indeed that do not have an answer from user Buffy! So go ahead, my only suggestion is to do them in batches of <= 5 so we don't flood the home page.

Comment: Oh: I would also suggest that if any of the questions you fix use the professor tag incorrectly, maybe remove that as well; we can kill 2 birds with one stone. For example, if a question is about "what to do after punching my professor", this shouldn't be tagged "professor" since the essential question would be the same if the assault victim were a non-professor instructor.

Comment: I'm keeping it to one or two at a time and normally when things are either boring or there is a lot of competition. And I'm playing with professor as I notice it. I did a couple of them recently. I see you've been busy also with older questions. I've been focusing on newer ones.

Comment: Has there been a change in the UI? I just noticed a question newly tagged students and it shows with a yellow/cream background. When I remove the tag it reverts to the standard background.

Comment: Do we/should we have the concept of a "deprecated" tag that is systematically being removed? Should its wiki indicate that?

Comment: Not aware of any changes, nor of a "deprecated" concept...I looked just now and don't see anything new. Anyway: adding "DEPRECATED - DO NOT USE" or something like that to the "students" wiki seems like a good idea.

Comment: I updated the usage wiki to reflect this. Maybe it should be done, also, for [tag:professors]. And the yellow background for the question was because I now "follow" that tag as well as professors.

Comment: I suspect we need a separate discussion about what to do with the professors tag. I think there may be a legitimate use for the tag, focused narrowly on questions that apply to professors and would not apply to other researchers and teachers (perhaps renaming it “professorship” would help). I will open such a discussion one of these days (or someone else can).

Comment: Good idea. And we are down nearly 100 questions tagged students.

Comment: @Buffy - one thing that just occurred to me. If we made "students" a synonym of "teaching," that would turn all of our "students" tags into "teaching" tags. Then we could undo the synonymization, leaving us with an empty "students" tag. Would save us the trouble of having to manually do the other 300. What do you think?

Comment: I'll look at a bunch of the questions. It might be necessary to make a pass and change a few first. Students was used in a lot of ways. I'll spend some time in the next couple of days.

Comment: I looked at a bunch of them, but very few were about teaching, actually. Cheating, funding, lots of other things. I think we probably just need to keep whittling. I'm focusing on those that are open with few answers and none accepted. I think you are attacking from the other end. None of my decisions have seemed hard, though I've had to come up with a few alternatives. Mostly just dropping it has worked ok. The problem will disappear if a few months.

Comment: We are closing out the tag. My intention was to leave the closed questions alone (there are about 20 of them left).  But then to raise the issue again.  I've also been retagging anything with [tag:student-employee]. Only three left to do. I'll probably finish today.

Comment: Good deal. I’ve been looking at the closed ones: have deleted a few, rewritten a few, and retagged some others.

Comment: All remaining questions tagged [tag:students] (13) are closed or dups. Should we finish the job or let the rest go unless brought back to life for other reasons? My inclination at the moment is to finish, which will take a few days.

Comment: Agree, let's finish, that tag is just too enticing to leave around and expect people not to use. I'll take another look and see if any are good candidates for deletion, though I think the low-hanging fruit has already been done. (update: yeah, I think the remaining 13 should not be deleted).

Comment: And done. The last of these has just been updated. You can close out this thread if you like.

Comment: yaaayyyy!!!!!!!

Answer (score -5):

It would have been better if we'd left this well enough alone. As @cag51 said in their answer, "Sadly, the only way to implement this would be to remove the tag from all 449 questions (which will bump each of the old questions back to the front page)."

So it's somewhat surprising that this was in fact the course that's been taken, for an issue that apparently only two people cared enough to speak about previously. Sure enough, the front page of SE Academia has been churned on a daily basis since then, with lots of half-decade old questions returning to the front page, and lots of clearly-confused posters writing comments and answers to questions that had already been settled years ago.

At a minimum, I recommend that very old tag-editing like this include a comment on the changed questions about why the edit in question has been made at the present time.

And I recommend that we not go through this again for other tags.

Comment: There is no intention to do anything similar with other "messy" tags such as [tag:professorship], which was improved a bit in other ways. A comment, IMO, would be worthless and even more distracting. I think that @cag51's comment was intended to refer to a one time bulk change rather than a piecemeal one. Continued...

Comment: The process of making [tag:students] obsolete will be over in another month. My current intention, unless we have another conversation about it is to leave the already closed questions as is and only deal with the still open ones. Many of them have no accepted answer. But quite a lot of the remaining questions are already closed - at least a third, though I haven't counted. More...

Comment: Another point to consider is that there is value in resurrecting old questions that might still be relevant. There is a bot that does this, in fact. Additionally, in removing students, I have also tried to add more appropriate (specific) tags when I can think of one or more, which increases the usefulness of the tagging system. More...

Comment: Moreover, a fair number of the affected questions have been answered anew with some rep earned and badges as well. And, FWIW, I try to do this in relatively "calm" periods on the site and only a few (2-3) at a time, which is less disruptive than If it were 20 or so. The last couple of weeks were pretty calm, I think, though it picked up today.

Comment: @DanielRCollins - In future, I would urge you to raise your objections when the original meta question is asked (which in this case was over two months ago). At this point, a consensus has already been reached and the work is largely finished. I, for one, have little patience for those who do not contribute to the discussion nor the labor but are keen to criticize the result.

Comment: @cag51: I object to the claim that a "consensus" was reached here and in other cases. The number of votes and interactions is far too small to claim any such thing.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins You're an established user participating to a few communities, and you should know by now that those are the typical number of votes and interactions of most Metas across the network, excluding a few huge ones like SO or Math. If users don't want to vote or write a counter-proposal at the right time, when a discussion is started, we cannot force them, but we won't look favourably to complaints written long afterwards. Note that usually, before implementing a proposal, we wait at least a couple of weeks, and there's plenty of time to comment .

Comment: Let me further add that having a few questions bumped every day for a limited period may not be so bad, because it allows us to do a bit of clean up (e.g. I deleted a few obsolete comments here and there) and it allows new users to discover old questions, and possibly add their contribution. After all, we're not a technical site, and many questions are not really "settled": if a user wants to contribute with a new perspective, even when there's already an accepted answer, they should feel welcome to do so.

Comment: To give you an example from another site, I posted [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/606244/111969) on Physics SE, seven years (!) after the question was posted, and the OP accepted it. And the same happened on [Cross-validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/214114/99484), where I answered to a question that was four years old. So, having people posting new answers to old questions is not that bad.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Knowingly giving high-quality answers to old questions: At no time have I critiqued that, it's a strawman. What the present case entails is, e.g., a rash of answers to several my questions which I've had to parse, all of which currently stand at zero or negative points. So: As far as I can tell, an increase in useless noise to the forum, with no value added.

Comment: What I specifically do not see on other SE sites in recent memory is a routinely strident claim to "consensus" from two or three people active in the meta; moderators independently deleting popular questions for "consensus" reasons of their own construction which then get re-opened by the actual community; deleting tags basic to the subject; letting the entire front page be churned for months on end; being endlessly argumentative; claiming to post answers when they don't; etc., etc. The behavior on SE Academia has very much become a regressive outlier.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Your questions are not merely your own, as they are hopefully useful to visitors and not just the person asking them. New answers to an old question of yours might not have value to you personally now, but that doesn't mean they won't have value to the next visitor (for whom their question is current/active in their minds). You can use the "questions" tab to avoid the churn if you prefer (I do wish it was easier to set this as a default by preference, but that's an issue for the SE software not academia mods).

Comment: @BryanKrause: Seems pretty ridiculous to argue that a rash of all zero- and negative-scored answers adds value to the site.

Comment: I think I was about as cautious as I could be by stating "might" and "doesn't mean they won't" have value. No ridiculous declarations that the new answers are excellent or better than the old. I count 4 answers to your bumped questions, one with positive score (+1), two with -1 (and no other votes), one with zero votes. Yeah, perhaps not the best collection of responses to those answers, but not sure I'd call it a "rash". Mostly just seems like they haven't had much exposure, despite the bumping, as there's just a total of 3 votes across 4 answers.

Comment: @BryanKrause: You discount 3 votes as not "much exposure", and yet approximately the same number of votes here in meta gets waved around as a "consensus" for mass deletions and edits. Highly hypocritical. Moderators should first do no harm to the site.

Comment: Three votes on four separate questions seems quite different from three votes on one, and I'm seeing more than three votes on the question and first answer here. I agree that moderators should avoid causing harm, but here it doesn't seem like there is agreement that there is a net harm here.

Comment: So I guess every single moderator is going to take the opportunity to argue about this. Good use of time. Very welcoming and inclusive.

Comment: Actually, I've quite enjoyed looking at some of these old Qs and have upvoted a few. 